# Knockout, ViewModel inside an other object and data-binding

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm doing a javascript application for a game, the goal is to make a "build calculator" for a MMORPG. I want to synchronize the view with data already stocked in my application. I searched and tested different framework, and knockout-js appeared to be the best solution for me

Html:

```
<script>
var simulatorTool = new SimulatorTool();
</script>

<body>
<p data-bind="text: test"> </p>
<p data-bind="text: test2"> </p>
</body>
```

Javascript Tool:

```
function SimulatorTool()
{

meSim = this;

this.config = new Config();
this.data = new Data();
this.stuff = new Stuff();
this.traits = new Traits();
this.view = new AppViewModel();
$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(meSim.view);
});

... functions

}
```

View Model:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.test = "Test!";

    this.test2 = ko.computed(function() {
        return meSim.data.selectedData['profession']
    }, this); 
}
```

The problem is that i don't know how to bind the html to the view in an other object. I don't even know if it's possible. I'd like to do something like that

```
 <p data-bind="simulatorTool.view, text: test"> </p>
```

If not, how can i access to the data inside "SimulatorTool" if the view is separated from the application ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is something like this - let's say in simulator_tool.js:

```
var SimulatorTool = SimulatorTool || {};

SimulatorTool.ViewModel = function(initialData){
  //bindings etc
};

SimulatorTool.Start - function(initialData){
  var viewModel = SimulatorTool.ViewModel(initialData);
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  return viewModel //if you want to play with it in the console...
};
```

Then, on your page:

```
<script>
$().ready(function()){

  var payload = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.SimulatorJSON);
  SimulatorTool.Start(payload);

}
</script>
```

Ideally you might have an application.js file where the SimulatorTool namespace is already set, so you can get rid of the declaration. I don't know if the JSON dump already sets the config, or if it's set somewhere else - but generally this all belongs in its own namespace using functions or whatnot:

```
SimulatorTool.Config = {

}

SimulatorTool.Stuff = {

}
//etc
```